# ajax call php page without reloading called page each time

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to call PHP page using AJAX but I don't want to reload PHP classes each time, for example, on first time running AJAX, PHP page load and set data, but on second time running AJAX, php get the same data from first time.

```js
function test() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "./test.php",
    method: "post",
    success: function(data) {
      $(document).find("body").append(`<p>${data}</p>`);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="test()">Click Me!</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
```

```php
//test.php
class Test{
    private $name = null;

    public function setName($name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }
}

$class = new Test;

if( $class->getName() == null ){
    echo "oops";
    $class->setName("pong");
} else {
    echo $class->getName();
}
```

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? This is currently a specification, not a question. Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service.

Comment: i just want to ask when calling ajax multiple times i want to store data in php class instance and on every call i want data from that instance.

Comment: Just adding "I want to ask" before a specification doesn't make it into a question. What have you tried and where are you stuck? What is your _specific_ issue? You need to show us your attempt and explain the issue. The question is currently too vague and unfocused. We're here to help you with specific and concrete issues. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (including all referenced pages)

Answer (score -1):

```
// Fire off the request to /form.php
request = $.ajax({
    url: "/form.php",
    type: "post",
    data: serializedData
});

// Callback handler that will be called on success
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    // Log a message to the console
 
});

// Callback handler that will be called on failure
request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    // Log the error to the console
    console.error(
        "The following error occurred: "+
        textStatus, errorThrown
    );
});

// if the request failed or succeeded
request.always(function () {
    //add your logic 
});
```

Comment: Before we should answer the question, the OP needs to show what they've tried and explain where they're stuck. And why are you assuming that they are using jQuery?

Comment: saving response of request will not help bcz i want to store response in php class instance and on next time calling ajax i want data from that instance.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson people who asked this question, how can we think they can always point where they stuck, they might don't know what will be easier for them, so I just did the trick, so he can speak up and for the beginner jQuery probably easier than ES to understand.

Comment: @Rishabh you can store data in session (temporary) / database.

Comment: @Arab - This site does actually require people to be able to do some basic debugging themselves before they ask. If they don't even know where they are stuck, then I would say they need to take a step back and start over, implementing one thing, get that to work, then the next thing and so on, doing one thing at the time. There's no real reason why someone wouldn't know where they are stuck.

Comment: Regarding jQuery, if the OP (or any future visitor) weren't using jQuery, this answer would be even more confusing since you don't even mention that it requires them to include a bloated library for the code to actually work. And tbh, if someone wants to learn Ajax, there are thousands of tutorials about doing it in vanilla JS today, which is not really that much harder to do than using jQuery.